# Replacing system calls (syscalls) in Linux 2.6+

Tags: multithreading, c++11, future, system-calls, promise

I'm looking into writing a [userland threading library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#N:1_.28User-level_threading.29), since there seems to be no active work in this area, and I believe the C++0x [promises and futures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)  may give this model some power. Unfortunately, in order to make this model work, it is essential to ensure a context switch on blocking calls. As such, I would like to intercept every syscall in order to replace it with an asynchronous version. There are some caveats:

- I know there are asynchronous syscalls for just about every regular syscall, but for backwards compatibility reasons this is not a viable solution.
- I know that in Linux 2.4 or earlier it was possible to directly change the sys_call_table, but this has vanished.
- As I would like my library to be statically linked if desired, the LD_PRELOAD trick isn't viable.
- Similarly, kernel modules are not an option because this is supposed to be a userland library.
- Finally, ptrace() is also not an option for similar reasons. I can't have my library forking a new process just in order to be used.

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems to me like a question not much related to syscalls but generally the linking mechanism. As usually nobody calls the syscalls in assembly code, you just want to replace some general functions with your own at link-time.

Comment: You know, I wonder if it's possible for a process to `ptrace` itself to make this happen? Even if it isn't, you might want to look into how `strace` intercepts system calls.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking into writing a userland threading library, since there seems to be no active work in this area

You might want to take a look at the thread libraries [Marcel](http://runtime.bordeaux.inria.fr/marcel/) (and its [publications](http://runtime.bordeaux.inria.fr/Publis/Keyword/MARCEL.html)) and [MPC](http://mpc.sourceforge.net/), which implement hybrid (kernel *and* user-level) threads, mainly in the purpose of High-Performance Computing, so they had to find some solution for this blocking system calls.

> So as to avoid the blocking of kernel threads when the application
>   makes blocking system calls, Marcel uses **Scheduler Activations** when
>   they are available, or just intercepts such blocking calls at dynamic
>   symbols level.

Comment: I've actually looked at Marcel, but unfortunately its license is incompatible with what I'm doing. Moreover, what you've posted suggests they are using the LD_PRELOAD trick and/or using shared libraries. Still, Marcel looks pretty sweet, so hopefully somebody else will have less strict requirements than me.